# Pygame error: 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'

Tags: python, pygame

I just downloaded Pygame but is running into an error: AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'. I was looking around on stackoverflow and someone fixed the error by renaming the files (which I don't know how to do). The directory is the following

Python -> Lib -> site-packages ->pygame

The confusing part for me is inside the pygame folder

```
pygame > Include, Lib
   Include > pygame > (many hh files)
   Lib > SitePackages > pygame > init (I know that it has the attribute init)
```

Since there is '3' pygame folder, is this causing the error for my program?

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
while True: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 20):

Just rename your file from  `pygame.py` to `myTestGame.py` for example; because you're importing the same file when you use `import pygame` !

Answer (score 4):

It looks as though you have "downloaded" a source distribution of pygame, and then copied the content into `site-packages`.  that works fine for most pure-python libraries, but not for ones with c-extensions, like pygame.  You are probably best served by using an installer, as pygame is a bit tedious to build from source.

Visit http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml and choose an *installer* for your OS.  note that the first two links are *source* downloads, and not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The most current, best way to install pygame is available at: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

Currently, for windows, it says to install it like this in a cmd window:
`py -m pip install pygame --user`

Answer (score 0):

Many windows users have difficulty installing Python, getting the path vars right and then adding in additional modules.  A convenient solution I find for many is to use a portable version they can put on USB (Or Desktop) and run anywhere, easily.

Download and install this: [Portable Python Pack](http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython2.7.6.1/)

Install to USB or Desktop

From the installed folder, open PyScripter (or another if you prefer)

Open and run your PyGame or other Python code.

NOTE: This is Python 2.7, but it has PyGame and a range of other modules packed in- check it out before download and try if suited to your needs!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install pygame.  If you did please try it with pip.  In terminal or command line type `pip install pygame` and if that does not work do `python -m pip install pygame` and if that does not work do `py -m pip install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

it's a common mistake which is not still fixed by now if you are running your code on a IDE like , "VSC" or "pycharm" and such a kind. you will get this error.

MAKE SURE that you have installed pygame correctly using pip and try to run the code using Git Bash (by typing `python filename.py`) or the python's interpreter.

you can also seek info at [www.pygame.org](http://www.pygame.org)

Answer (score 0):

1 first `uninstall` your `IDE`

2 `reinstall IDE` in another folder

3 goto `IDE terminal and install Pygame using pip version 19.0.3`

4 Then your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

i recommend y'all to use this code

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame Title")

def close():
    sys.exit()
    pygame.quit()

while True:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               close()
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
python -m pip uninstall pygame
python -m pip install pygame
```

This should reinstall pygame.