# Error with pygame (pygame.init())

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having an error while using Pygame.
I'm using Python 3.5 and Pygame 3.2. I started to learn Pygame just today and it gives me this error:

Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")


while 1:
    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(player, (100,100))
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            exit(0)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
pygame.init()
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame attribute, init()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912810/pygame-attribute-init)

Comment: How did you install pygame? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34344103/4014959) _may_ help. Another possibility is that you have a script named `pygame.py` in the directory you're running `test.py` from (or elsewhere in your PYTHONPATH) that's shadowing the real pygame module.

Answer (score 0):

try moving your pygame folder in the same file where this code is, and delete or move any other file named pygame.py
If neither of that works, try cleaning your python folders by uninstalling and installing python. Then install pygame by doing the following:

1.)  go to: [This website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) and download the correct version of pygame

2.)  move the download to your python - scripts folder

3.)  then highlight the download and shift - right click on an empty space in the file explorer

4.)  select: open command window here

5.)  type in : pygame.install.(download name)

where download name is type in the name of the pygame you downloaded( you can just type in pygame and press tab for short)

Answer (score -1):

Delete the "pygame.py" file in your Documents folder, it is shadowing the real pygame you've installed.

Comment: I have no pygame.py file in my documents folder nor any other folder.